# Run code when date in DatePicker is changed in SwiftUI didSet function?

Tags: swift, swiftui, didset

```
struct ViewName: View {
    @State private var selectedDay: Date = Date() {
        didSet {
            print("Old value was \(oldValue) and new date is \(self.selectedDay)")
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker(selection: $selectedDay, in: Date()..., displayedComponents: .date) { Text("") }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, when I'm setting the selectedDate value in the DatePicker, why is there nothing printed to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, when I'm setting the selectedDate value in the DatePicker, why is there nothing printed to the console?

For now `didSet` does not work for `@State` property wrapper.

Here is an approach to have side effect on DatePicker selection changed

```
struct ViewName: View {
    @State private var selectedDay = Date()

    var body: some View {
        let dateBinding = Binding(
            get: { self.selectedDay },
            set: {
                print("Old value was \(self.selectedDay) and new date is \($0)")
                self.selectedDay = $0
            }
        )
        return VStack {
            DatePicker(selection: dateBinding, in: Date()..., displayedComponents: .date) { Text("") }
        }
    }
}
```